# How to send array of images to rdlc reports?

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I need to send a title and some images to a report, this is my class

```
public class ReportDataModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<byte[]> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

when i create a report file and set this class as the data source class and then in design i drag the image field on the report, on run time instead of images it shows "#Error".
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `ReportDataModel` uses a master-detail structure. It would not therefore be possible to drag drop images property to the report without showing `"#Error"`, unless you are using an expression like `First(Fields!Image.Value)`.

Change `ReportDataModel` to the following:

```
  public  class ReportDataModel
  {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public byte[] Image { get; set; } 
  }
```

Then instead of dragging the `Image` field directly on the report, drag an **Image** from the **ToolBox**, set image source to Database, select your image field and set MIME type.